# How to add a JComboBox to a JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to add JComponents to JTable Cells. Do I Implement CellRenderer or CellEditor?

Answer (score 7):

What you need is a custom editor which will return the JComboBox (or whatever component you want to use). You should check the [Sun tutorial for JTable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), it contains an example on how to use a JComboBox as an editor. If you want to use JComboBox as a renderer as well, the tutorial applies to that too.

Comment: yep, just keep in mind that renderer is for display and editor is for when editing a cell.  You may only need to implement Editor :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with the [DefaultCellEditor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) by passing in an instance of a JComboBox (or JCheckBox or JTextField) to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a `JCombobox` and insert into it the information you want, like this:

```
JComboBox<String> sport = new JComboBox<String>();
sport.addItem("foot");
sport.addItem("hand bool");
sport.addItem("****");
```

2- Create a `JTable` and set a Table Mode to this table, something like:

```
Vector<String> title = new Vector<String>
title.add("id");
title.add("sport");
Vector<Vector<String>> rows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
rows.addItem("1");
rows.addItem("2");

JTable table = new JTable(rows, title);
```

3- You put the JComboBox in JTable Cells like this:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(sport));
```