# Create JTable from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Now that I managed to put the objects from a file into a `ArrayList`, I have to display them into a `JTable`.

These are the 3 objects contained in my `ArrayList`

```
Lieu<Double, String>(45.573715, -73.900295, "p1");
Lieu<Double, String>(45.573882, -73.899748, "p2");
Lieu<Double, String>(45.574438, -73.900099, "p3");
```

In the `Lieu` class I have the methods `getX()` and `getY()`

But I can't figure out how to diplay them in a `JTable`.

```
Longitude           Latitude
45.573715           -73.900295
45.573882           -73.899748
45.574438           -73.900099
```

Here's what I have for a start:

```
public class MonModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return l.size();//l is the arraylist that contains the 3 elements
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex==0){
            return l.get(rowIndex).getX();
        }
        else if(columnIndex==1){
            return l.get(rowIndex).getY();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your `TableModel` to create a `JTable` and add it to a `JFrame`. Also consider overriding `getColumnName()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513). See also [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

```
MonModel model = new MonModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
f.pack();
f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TableModel` for showing data in the `JTable`. For Example:

In UI class, set the table model to the table.

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MonModel());
```

Table Model class

```
class MonModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<LatNLon> l;
    private String[] columnNames = {"Longitude", "Latitude"};

    public MonModel() {
        l = new ArrayList<LatNLon>();

        l.add(new LatNLon("45.573715", "-73.900295"));
        l.add(new LatNLon("45.573715", "-73.900295"));
        l.add(new LatNLon("45.573715", "-73.900295"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return l.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex==0){
            return l.get(rowIndex).getX();
        }
        else if(columnIndex==1){
            return l.get(rowIndex).getY();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Latitude and Longitude class.

```
class LatNLon {
    private String x;
    private String y;

    public LatNLon(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
// Code: For Getters and Setters.
}
```

Also read [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).