# Is there a way to put an ArrayList into a JTable where each line is the next index of the ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have many different array lists. I want each index to be a new row in the JTable but I'm not sure how to do that. I made a for loop but it is not working.
Is there even a way to populate a JTable with an array list and not an array?

```
 public TableCreator() {
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));

    String[] columnNames = {"Item Type",
      "Description",
      "Size",
      "Price"};
    // for(int i=0; i<ShoppingFunctions.cartType.size(); i++){

    for(int i=0; i<GUI.size.size(); i++){//FIX!!!!
      item = ShoppingFunctions.cartType.get(i)+"\n";
      described = GUI.describe[GUI.imageNum];
      sizes = GUI.size.get(i);
      price = ShoppingFunctions.cartPrice.get(i)+"\n";
    }//end of for


   Object[][] data = {{item, described, sizes, price}};


    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    if (DEBUG){
      table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
          printDebugData(table);
        }//end of method
      });//end of listener
    }//end of if

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);
  }//end of method
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a custom table model: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Yes, make your own TableModel class, one that extends AbstractTableModel, and use your ArrayList as the data nucleus of your TableModel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create JTable from ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956187/create-jtable-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to create your own, based on something like `AbstractTableModel`

For example...

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericTableModel<R> extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected ArrayList<R> rows;
    protected List columnIdentifiers;

    public AbstractGenericTableModel() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public AbstractGenericTableModel(int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        this(new ArrayList(columnCount), rowCount);
    }

    public AbstractGenericTableModel(List columnNames, int rowCount) {
        setData(new ArrayList<>(rowCount), columnNames);
    }

    public AbstractGenericTableModel(List<R> data, List columnNames) {
        setData(data, columnNames);
    }

    public List<R> getRowData() {
        return rows;
    }

    private List nonNullVector(List v) {
        return (v != null) ? v : new ArrayList();
    }

    public void setData(List<R> data, List columnIdentifiers) {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<>(nonNullVector(data));
        this.columnIdentifiers = nonNullVector(columnIdentifiers);
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(R rowData) {
        insertRow(getRowCount(), rowData);
    }

    public void insertRow(int row, R rowData) {
        rows.add(row, rowData);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the row at <code>row</code> from the model. Notification of the row being removed will be sent to all the listeners.
     *
     * @param row the row index of the row to be removed
     * @exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the row was invalid
     */
    public void removeRow(int row) {
        rows.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

    public void setColumnIdentifiers(List columnIdentifiers) {
        setData(rows, columnIdentifiers);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnIdentifiers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        Object id = null;
        // This test is to cover the case when
        // getColumnCount has been subclassed by mistake ...
        if (column < columnIdentifiers.size() && (column >= 0)) {
            id = columnIdentifiers.get(column);
        }
        return (id == null) ? super.getColumnName(column)
                        : id.toString();
    }

}

public class ArrayListTableModel extends AbstractGenericTableModel<ArrayList> {

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        List<ArrayList> rows = getRowData();
        return rows.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

}
```

This creates two classes, an "abstract generics" based model, which allows you to specify the physical data which backs a row and a `ArrayListTableModel` which allows you to use a `ArrayList` for the individual data.

What this assumes though, is each row has the same number of elements, but it makes no checks

I suggest you have a closer look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [List Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/). It will support rows of data stored in an `ArrayList`, `Vector` or any other class that implements the `List` interface.

The `ListTableModel` is also based on a generic TableModel that allows you to add Objects to a row in the model. There are many row based methods that allow easy usage of the model

The `ListTableModel` provides methods that allow you to easily customize the model:

1. setColumnClass – specify the class of individual columns so the proper renderer/editor can be used by the table.
2. setModelEditable – specify editable property for the entire model.
3. setColumnEditable – specify editable property at a column level. This property will have preference over the model editable property.

The other option is to iterate through the `ArrayList` and copy each row of data to a `Vector` and then add the `Vector` to the `DefaultTableModel` using the `addRow(...)` method.