# How to add colum JTable to Jcombobox in Java Eclipse

Tags: java

I add the column value of `JTable` to `JComBoBox` full of null notifications

I tried passing the sub-variable and then adding jcombobox but it was not

I have test two ways but failed

```
1.TableColumn testColumn = tbclass.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
testColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcombobox));

2.tbclass.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcombobox));
```

The error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat
```

Comment: Can you please give a bit more details ?

Comment: I added a column in Jtable to Jcombobox but I still get an error saying NullPoint can you help me?

Comment: Could you just complete the error in the question ? And also here is a reference to your question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355712/adding-jcombobox-to-a-jtable-cell)